# Difference between basis of a NULL space and a solution space?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

I've been tasked to find the basis of the solution space to the matrix

$A=\pmatrix{1&-3&1\\2&-6&2\\3&-9&3}$

I've row reduced this matrix to:

$\pmatrix{1&-3&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$

From there I've set $x_{2} = s, x_{3} = t$ and thus $x_{1} = 3s - t$ and thus:

$\pmatrix{x_{1},&x_{2},&x_{3}} = (3s-t, s, t) = (3s, s, 0) + (-t,0,t) = s(3,1,0) + t(-1,0,1)$

So the basis of $A$ is $B = \{(3,1,0), (-1,0,1)\}$

What I don't understand is.. isn't this the NULL space? The resulting vector if I multiply my original matrix $A$ with these are the NULL matrix. The same occurs if I change t and s. For example putting $s=1.5, t=1$ gives $(4.5,1.5,1)$ but this is also just the NULL vector if I multiply it by A.

So my questions are:

1. What are the differences between the NULL space and solution space? They seem to be deduced by the same method, and the result seem to yield the same thing?
2. Can you find all vectors in the NULL space which are not in the solution space or vice versa?

Comment: The basis of the column space of $A$ is just $(1,2,3)$. The “solution space” I assume is what you mean for column space

Comment: The nullspace is two dimensional and must span $x-3y+z=0$ (the nullspace is this plane, visually)

Comment: See a similar example with a non square matrix, can you see anything?

Comment: The exercise is to find "a basis for the NULL space N(F) and a basis for the solution space V(F)". I've tried to find approaches as to how to do this, but it seems as if finding a basis for the NULL space is the same as finding a basis for the solution space so I'm very confused

Comment: @Cenderze Write explicitly in your post the definition of "NULL space N(F) and Solution Space V(F)". You need to be precise in maths.